# NodeJS write or delete cookies on a specific route

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I have to do an app for the university ( and I'm not allowed to use express or other similar modules ) and I was wondering how do you specify the route on which you write a cookie. Why ?

So far I've noticed that cookies are stored mainly on domains, but if u set a cookie on localhost:3000/ the cookie will be on the subroutes too, however if you set a cookie on localhost:3000/someroute, then that cookie won't be on "/" .

> So how do you set a cookie on "/" when you are on "/someRoute" and as
>   well how can you delete a cookie ?

This is how I've been writing on cookies so far

```
res.writeHead(302, { 'Set-Cookie': 'session='+sessionID });
```

> - Please Note that I ask how you edit those cookies on specific routes, and not how they work

Comment: @Brad Please Note that I ask how you edit those cookies on specific routes, and not how they work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Path directive.

```
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie> 
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; Expires=<date>
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; Max-Age=<non-zero-digit>
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; Domain=<domain-value>
**Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; Path=<path-value>**
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; Secure
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; SameSite=Strict
Set-Cookie: <nome-cookie>=<valor-cookie>; SameSite=Lax
```

In your case:

```
Set-Cookie: Path=/something;
```

Further reading: [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple nodejs http server setup to read, set and delete cookie

```
const http = require("http");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3003;

const setCookie = (res, name, value, opts) => {
    let str = name + "=" + value;

    if(opts){
        if(opts.expires){
            str += "; Expires=" + opts.expires.toUTCString();
        }
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Set-Cookie": str
    });
}

const routes = [
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/",
        callback: (req, res) => {
            return "hello at /";
        }
    },
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/set-cookie",
        callback: (req, res) => {
            setCookie(res, "mycookie", "test")
            return "Cookie set `mycookie` with value `test`";
        }
    },
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/get-cookie",
        callback: (req, res) => {
            return JSON.stringify(parseCookies(req));
        }
    },
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/delete-cookie",
        callback: (req, res) => {
            return setCookie(res, "mycookie", "test", {expires: new Date(0)});
        }
    }
];

const parseCookies = (req) => {
    const list = {};
    const cookie = req.headers.cookie;

    cookie && cookie.split(';').forEach(function( c ) {
        var parts = c.split('=');
        list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
    });

    return list;
}

const routeMatches = (original, requested) => {
    return original === requested; // basic string match without any pattern checking etc...
}

const handleRoute = (req, res) => {
    const _path = req.url;
    const _method = req.method;

    for(let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++){

        const route = routes[i];

        if(route.method === _method && routeMatches(route.path, _path)){
            return route.callback(req, res);
        }
    }
    return "404, Not Found " + _path;
};

const handleRequest = (req, res) => {
    const response = handleRoute(req, res);
    res.end(response);
};

const server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

`handleRequest` handles all of the requests passed down to this basic server.

`handleRoute` method is a very simple parser. This function basically take all the incoming requests to the server and matches the `url` with the registered routes on the `routes` array defined above and return response by invoking the `callback` method.

There are three other helper methods: `setCookie` to set the cookie in the response header, `parseCookie` to parse the raw cookies from the request header in a key value pair and `routeMatches` to check if the provided paths matches.

`/set-cookie` path would simply set a cookie in the header
`/get-cookie` path would get the list of cookies
`/delete-cookie` path would delete the cookie set in the `/set-cookie` path

A quick note, You can't really delete a cookie, you can set the expire time to a previous time than now which will remove the cookie from the jar.

Hope this helps.